# Problem with will_paginate and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, will-paginate

## Stack

1. ruby => 1.9.2-head
2. rails => 3.0.1
3. will_paginate => (3.0.pre2)
4. mongo => (1.1.5)
5. mongoid => (2.0.0.beta.20)
6. mongoid_slug => (0.4.6)

## Console

```
r = Radar.criteria
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria:0x00000104753d48 @selector={}, @options={}, @klass=Radar,     @documents=[]> 
r.map(&:title) 
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

r.active.around(Radius.new,current_location).newest.map(&:title)
=> ["6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
```

### Problem

Step 1

```
r.active.around(Radius.new,current_location).newest.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 3).map(&:title)
=> ["3", "2", "1"] ]
```

Step 2

```
r.active.around(Radius.new,current_location).newest.paginate(:page => 2, :per_page => 3).map(&:title)
=>["3", "2", "1"]
```

**In Step1 pagination should return => ["6", "5", "4]**

When I change newest to most_commented scope everything works fine.

```
r.active.around(Radius.new,current_location).most_commented.map(&:title)
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

r.active.around(Radius.new,current_location).most_commented.paginate(:page =>1 ,:per_page => 3).map(&:title)
=> ["1", "2", "3"]

r.active.around(Radius.new,current_location).most_commented.paginate(:page =>2 ,:per_page => 3).map(&:title)
=> ["4", "5", "6"]
```

## Scopes used in conole

```
 scope :most_commented, :order_by => [:comment_count,:desc]
 scope :newest, :order_by => [:created_at,:desc]  

 def self.around(distance,location)
  radius = distance.to_rad
  near(:coords => location.coords + [radius])
 end
```

ps: I always use new r=Radar.criteria in each example I removed that from output for simplification

Comment: I don't see anything. What your real problem ?

Comment: I update my question it looks better now. I describe my problem in Problem paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I found that .near doesent work well with skip

ruby-1.9.2-head > r = Radar.criteria

### Everything works

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > r.active.near(:coords => ul.coords).newest.map(&:title)
=> ["6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
```

### Same query but with .skip

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > r.active.near(:coords => ul.coords).newest.skip(2).map(&:title)
=> []
```

### First query with .skip but without .near

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > r.active.newest.skip(2).map(&:title)
=> ["4", "3", "2", "1"]
```